# Firefox debugger server keeps asking to "Allow connection" when a GET request is sent to it

Tags: firefox, google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging, firefox-developer-tools

I have followed the instructions on [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Remote_Debugging/Debugging_Firefox_Desktop) to enable remote debugging on Firefox desktop and start a debugger server on, for example, port 6000.

However every time I send a GET request to `http://localhost:6000`, a pop-up coming from Firefox (the instance that is running the debugger server) shows up:

```
An incoming request to permit remote debugging connection was detected. A remote client can
take complete control over your browser!

Client Endpoint: 127.0.0.1:PORT-THAT-KEEPS-CHANGING
Server Endpoint: 127.0.0.1:6000

[OK] [Disable] [Cancel]
```

The GET request instantly fails for reasons such as `Connection aborted` and clicking `OK` doesn't allow the next request to succeed.

Am I missing something?

I am planning to send a request to `http://localhost:6000/json/` to get a list of the active tabs and retrieve WebSocket connection URLs to perform some actions, similarly to what can be done using the [Chrome DevTools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/).

Comment: I'm having the same problem except when trying to connect to FF from Visual Studio (rather than sending a request via the browser). But the symptoms are the same - I get a "rejected" message from VS before I can accept the prompt shown by FF. Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: @dwillis77 I still have a few problems while using remote debugging with FF but I found a way so that the popup no longer shows up (and so that remote debugging is allowed by default). I don't have access to my machine right now and I don't remember the details, so I'll come back to you in a few hours (>8h) to provide you an answer. Feel free to tag me if I were to forget.

Comment: @dwillis77 So first of all, I'm using a separate profile using the `--profile profile_name` flag, I also specify `--new-instance` and `--remote debugging-port=1234`. In addition to this, I'm creating a `user.js` file that overrides FF's default config. In this file, I add the following lines: `user_pref("devtools.chrome.enabled", true);` `user_pref("devtools.debugger.prompt-connection", false);` `user_pref("devtools.debugger.remote-enabled", true);` (not sure about this last one).

Comment: @dwillis77 You may also need to add the two following lines to `user.js` for CDP to work (it is explained here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1746154#c4): `user_pref("fission.bfcacheInParent", false);` and `user_pref("fission.webContentIsolationStrategy", 0);`.

Answer (score 1):

The options to connect a client and send packets to Firefox remote debugging are sockets (TCP and Web).

The packet format does not recognize any transport protocol.

> The protocol is carried by a reliable, bi-directional byte stream; data sent in both directions consists of JSON objects, called packets. A packet is a top-level JSON object, not contained inside any other value.

and

> Once the underlying byte stream is established, transport participants may immediately begin sending packets, using the forms described here. The transport requires no initial handshake or setup, and no shutdown exchange: the first bytes on the stream in each direction are those of the first packet, if any; the last bytes on the stream in each direction are the final bytes of the last packet sent, if any.

From https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools/backend/protocol.html